# Doppio avverbio che termina con mente

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Reminiscenze di scuola, mi ricordano che l'uso di un doppio avverbio che termina con il suffisso `-mente` è errato o quanto meno cacofonico.

Oggi mi sono imbattuto in questa frase

> Taranto fu probabilmente scientificamente scelta per portarvi il
>   peggio della produzione italiana

Che io correggerei nel seguente modo:

> Taranto fu probabilmente, in modo scientifico, scelta per portarvi il
>   peggio della produzione italiana

Volevo sapere, non sono riuscito a trovarlo in rete, se c'è una regola che vieta l'uso del doppio avverbio in -mente o se è solo lasciato al buon senso di chi scrive.

Comment: È molto allitterativo :) Si può considerare un omoteleuto?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Beh seguendo la definizione direi di sì, quindi dici, la frase da me postata è corretta. Resta solo l'aspetto cacofonico quindi, giusto?

Comment: A mio parere, sì. Sarebbe forse maggiormente "lecita" una cosa del genere, se si volesse usare una sfilza di avverbi a mo' di "martellamento", una cosa del tipo:  _"Taranto fu probabilmente, scientificamente, dolosamente, criminalmente..."_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In effetti generalmente si ritiene che due avverbi in “-mente” troppo ravvicinati non suonino bene, e così anche più in generale tutte le cosiddette rime involontarie (per esempio due o più aggettivi e participi in “-ato” troppo vicini). Ma è una questione di stile, non di regole grammaticali.

Per esempio, Gadda, nelle sue [*Norme per la redazione di un testo radiofonico*](https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=es&id=vx5tDwAAQBAJ&q=%22rime+involontarie%22&f=false#v=onepage&q&f=false) del 1953, scrive:

> Evitare le rime involontarie, obbrobrio dello scritto, del discorso, ma in ogni modo del parlato radiofonico. Una rima non voluta e inattesa travolge al ridicolo l'affermazione più pregna di senso, il proposito più grave. La regìa si riserva la facoltà di emendare dal vezzo d'una rima il testo che ne andasse eventualmente adorno.